# How can I read standard input in a loop in bash, and then append the text to a file?

Tags: bash, macos, file, scripting, echo

Say I have a bash script as follows

```
while
 read $f;
do
 cat $f >> output.txt;
 echo "aaa" >> output.txt;
done
```

Yet the second `echo` statement isn't executed. At all. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running this via

```
tail -f /var/log/somelog | ./script.sh
```

`$f` should not be empty. It's only supposed to output when `tail` notices a change in the file.

Comment: `bash -x <scriptname>` is your friend here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `$f` is probably empty, and your script is hanging on a call to `cat` with no arguments. Did you want to say

```
while read f
```

instead of

```
while read $f
```

?

Comment: Everything works find until I add the `echo "aaa">>output.txt;` line. I'm piping in a `tail` command. Question updated.

Comment: @mobrule: It's not empty, at least it ceases to become empty when something get's written to the file it's tailing. As mentioned this works fine without the second echo.

Comment: @Josh K: using variables like that is "doing it wrong". Use `while read f`, not `while read $f`. Your code evaluates to: `while read; do cat >> output.txt; ...; done`. Also, always quote variables you use to at least get some error message from `cat` (in this case); i.e. `cat "$f"` with an empty/undefined `$f` would result in `cat: : No such file or directory`.

Comment: So remove the `$` from all instances?

Comment: @Josh: No, when you're setting the value of the variable there's usually no `$`. When you're using the value, you do use `$`. The exception to the first "rule" is when you're using indirection (`x=y; read $x; echo $y` will output the value entered to the read statement (e.g. "4"). If you did `echo $x` it will say "y". To get the value of an indirection: `echo ${!x}` which might output "4". But indirection is not what you want in this case).